# cytoscape js box selection and highlight

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

There are 3 nodes in the example,I use modifier key + mousedown then drag,I can select 2 nodes and drag them,the problem is after I release the mouse,I can not see which nodes I have selected.They are not highlight or with shadow or reversed color or with some sign to mark they are selected.

```
<style>
    #cy{
        width:600px;
        height:800px
    }
</style>
<script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
<div id="cy"></div>
<script>
var cy = cytoscape({

  container: document.getElementById('cy'), // container to render in

  elements: [ // list of graph elements to start with
    { // node a
      data: { id: 'a' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'b' }
    },
    { // node c
      data: { id: 'c' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' }
    }
  ],

  style: [ // the stylesheet for the graph
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'background-color': '#666',
        'label': 'data(id)'
      }
    },

    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'width': 3,
        'line-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],

  layout: {
    name: 'grid',
    rows: 1
  },
  boxSelectionEnabled:true,
   panningEnabled: true
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the selected node(s) in a variable or array and then add a mouseUp event, in which you highlight the nodes in said variable or array.

http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/user-input-device-events

Here you find the bind for cytoscape (always unbind events before binding them again):
http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.on

```
cy.unbind('mouseup');
cy.bind('mouseup',/* 'node', */ function () {});
```